# True vim-like behavior in Chromium

Tags: chrome

I have been struggling in the browser wars for years, and I think I have finally found an extension ([chromium-vim](https://github.com/1995eaton/chromium-vim)) which allows me to switch away from Firefox (or more recently, [palemoon](http://www.palemoon.org/)) for good. However, there are two things that still bug me and I am not sure how to overcome them (search engines have not aided me as they normally do):

1. I use an extension to achieve vim-like modal browsing so I do not need the URL bar (it is now just wasted screen real-estate. I know, once upon a time, there was a flag to disable the URL bar, but it appears to have disappeared. How can I disable the URL bar (but keep the tab bar)?
2. I have the flag in `chrome://flags` set to allow extensions to function on `chrome://` URLs, but it seems cvim still does not function on `chrome://` URLs. Is this a chromium issue, or an extension issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, not anymore, though I wish they would. It was discontinued be cause the moving around was distracting. I remember how much I hate when (I think firefox's) back button would slide away on pages that didn't have a history and swoop back in when you followed a link. I guess I see their point. though I would really just leave it hidden all the time personally.
2. The author of cvim addresses this on reddit:

> You can actually make cVim run on chrome://* pages, but it requires a
>   bit of tweaking. You'll have to download cVim from my [GitHub
>   repository](https://github.com/1995eaton/chromium-vim), and edit the line in the manifest.json file look like
>   this:
>
> `"matches": ["<all_urls>"],`
>
> to look like this:
>
> `"matches":["<all_urls>","chrome://*/*"],`
>
> Then you'll have to enable the Chrome flag found at
>   chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls.

I've tested it and it sure does work
source: http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/28af5n/cvim_now_with_more_features/ci90r6e

Comment: This definitely addresses issue #2. Well-done! Any ideas about issue #1?

Comment: That's the downside of condensing two questions in one :)